# Access Sharepoint Images from app

Tags: javascript, rest, app, image

I'm in the process of setting up a REST call to access images in a SP folder via Office365.  My question is where do I add my onedrive credentials as part of the REST call?  Once the call is completed(image downloaded), can I simply reference in the app via the url?

```
function getMaps() {

url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')/$value

method: GET

headers:    

Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet, it appears that you are writing Javascript. If so, then the browser will automatically handle the 401 response and pass the auth token of the current user on your behalf.

If you attempting to use App Only policy, then you will need to do so in a provider-hosted app, and your app will need to use the pre-configured AppId (ClientID) and AppSecret (ClientSecret) to authenticate and receive a token (which is then passed to SharePoint as you show).

Be aware -- the OneDrive for Business API for Office365 is different than the SharePoint API for reading libraries. (They will eventually converge, but for now they are different.)

Comment: I think I am headed in the right direction then.  Still a bit fuzzy on the authentication though.  If I'm allowing my SP files to be visible to app users and requiring no login on their part, how is it authenticating in SP API?